# Side-effecting an array in an association?

Tags: evaluation, associations

I'm working on some classical data structures (stack, queue, etc.) and want to mimic oo style in MMA. As a first attempt, I want to store an array in an Association, like this:

```
q = <|elems -> ConstantArray[Null, 4]|>
```

> ```
> <|elems -> {Null, Null, Null, Null}|>
> ```

Later, I want to side-effect my array, like this

```
q[elems][[2]] = 42;
```

> Set::setps: q[elems] in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>

Ahh, yes, of course, I need a symbol... Next attempt is this:

```
q = Module[{storage = ConstantArray[Null, 4]},
  <|elems -> Hold[storage]|>]
```

> ```
> <|elems -> Hold[storage$1987]|>
> ```

```
In[4]:= ReleaseHold[q[elems]][[2]] = 42
```

> During evaluation of In[4]:= Set::setps: ReleaseHold[q[elems]] in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>
>
> ```
>  42
> ```

Oh, yeah, that's not going to work.

I could do the following, but it's going to copy the array every time and defeat the purpose of implementing classical algorithms (that being "efficiency"):

```
q = <|elems -> ConstantArray[Null, 4]|>;
SetAttributes[setQ, HoldFirst];
setQ[q_, slot_, item_] :=
  Module[{newElems = q[elems]},
   newElems[[slot]] = item;
   q[elems] = newElems;
   q[elems]];
setQ[q, 2, 42]
```

> ```
> {Null, 42, Null, Null}
> ```

It looks like I need some kind of variant of `Part` that doesn't evaluate a held symbol on its left-hand side -- a `PartHoldFirst`. I don't see a way to do this with stuff I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand what you're trying to do, but...

```
q = <|elems -> ConstantArray[Null, 4]|>

q[[1, 2]] = 42;

q
```

> ```
> <|elems -> {Null, 42, Null, Null}|>
> ```

```
q[[Key[elems], 4]] = 99;
```

> ```
> <|elems -> {Null, 42, Null, 99}|>
> ```

So whether you set by position or `Key` it works.

Comment: Interesting -- you can index into Associations with `Part` (double brackets) & `Key` (for non-string keys) as well as with single-brackets, function-call notation, and then you can continue to index into them with commas in the double brackets, similarly to levels in ordinary lists.  I hadn't appreciated this fact deeply enough.

Comment: A bigger question is "why have the function-call notation at all?" It seems the double-bracket does at least as much, plus it obviously does much more, enabling whole scenarios like oop-emulation.

Comment: Another implication of positional notation is that order does matter, that, intentionally, `<|a->1,b->2|>=!=<|b->2,a->1|>` but `Sort[<|a->1,b->2|>]===Sort[<|b->2,a->1|>]`. I sometimes wonder how web programmers deal with the fact that determining equality of two JSON objects without a canonical ordering on keys is combinatorial in the number of keys. Maybe JSON objects have a canonical ordering on keys.

Comment: I found out something that functional notation `[...]` can do and that part notation `[[...]]` can't do: side-effectfully add a key. Let `t = <|"a"->1|>`, then `t[["b"]]=2` succeeds and produces `2`, but `t` is still `<|"a"->1|>`. Now `t["b"]=2` succeeds and produces `2`, but `t` is now modified and equals `<|"a"->1, "b"->2|>`.

Comment: @Reb Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 3):

I had a flash of insight and did the following. Notice particularly the **necessary** `RuleDelayed` on the `elems` tag in the association:

```
q = Module[{storage = ConstantArray[Null, 4]},
      <|elems :> storage, set -> ((storage[[#1]] = #2) &)|>];
q[set][2, 42];
q[elems]
```

> ```
> {Null, 42, Null, Null}
> ```