# Functional-Style Fixed-Length Queue Object?

Tags: evaluation, associations

Following up on question [Side-effecting an array in an association?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57515/side-effecting-an-array-in-an-association/57521#57521) and @Mr.Wizard's answer in there, I'm modernizing and tweaking [Daniel Lichtblau's efficient queues](http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf99/lichtblau/Links/index_lnk_7.html) and ran into a little roadblock.

First, I came up with the following API, stripped-down for brevity. The queue I want is fixed-length and lossy. Make a new queue with `newQ[capacity]`. Push values to the back with `pushQ[aQueue, aValue]`; pop values from the front with `popQ[aQueue]`, just like a queue of humans. If the queue is full, just pop the value at the front, losing it (on purpose)

I want `pushQ` to return the queue it receives, so that I can fold it and chain it as follows:

```
Fold[pushQ, newQ[4], Range[10]]
```

Here's what I came up with, with the functional mojo highlighted:

```
ClearAll[newQ, emptyQQ, fullQQ, pushQ, popQ, peekQ, bumpQ]; 
newQ[cap_Integer] /; cap > 0 :=
  <|"storage" -> ConstantArray[Null, cap],
   "len"    -> 0, "cap"   -> cap,
   "iFront" -> 1, "iBack" -> 1|>;
emptyQQ[Q_] := Q[["len"]] === 0;
fullQQ[Q_]  := Q[["len"]] === Q[["cap"]];
peekQ[Q_]   := Q[["storage", Q[["iFront"]]]];
SetAttributes[bumpQ, HoldFirst];
bumpQ[Q_, index_] := Q[[index]] = Mod[Q[[index]] + 1, Q[["cap"]], 1];
SetAttributes[pushQ, HoldFirst];
pushQ[Q_, item_] :=
  (Q[["storage", Q[["iBack"]]]] = item;
   bumpQ[Q, "iBack"];
   If[fullQQ[Q],
    (*then*)bumpQ[Q, "iFront"],
    (*else*)Q[["len"]]++];
   Q); (* <<<<<<< HERE IS THE FUNCTIONAL MOJO <<<<<<<< *)
SetAttributes[popQ, HoldFirst];
popQ[Q_] /; emptyQQ[Q] := Null;
popQ[Q_] :=
 (Q[["len"]]--;
  With[ {result = Q[["storage", Q[["iFront"]]]]},
   Q[["storage", Q[["iFront"]]]] = Null;
   bumpQ[Q, "iFront"];
   result ])
```

This passes a bunch of unit tests:

```
$q = newQ[4];
pushQ[$q, 1]; $q["storage"]
```

> ```
> {1, Null, Null, Null}
> ```

```
pushQ[$q, 2]; $q["storage"]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, Null, Null}
> ```

```
pushQ[$q, 3]; $q["storage"]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, Null}
> ```

```
popQ[$q]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

```
$q["storage"]
```

> ```
> {Null, 2, 3, Null}
> ```

```
popQ[$q]; $q["storage"]
```

> ```
> {Null, Null, 3, Null}
> ```

```
pushQ[$q, 4]; $q["storage"]
```

> ```
> {Null, Null, 3, 4}
> ```

```
pushQ[$q, 5]; $q["storage"]
```

> ```
> {5, Null, 3, 4}
> ```

```
popQ[$q]
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

```
$q["storage"]
```

> ```
> {5, Null, Null, 4}
> ```

```
pushQ[$q, 6]; pushQ[$q, 7]; pushQ[$q, 8]; pushQ[$q, 9]; pushQ[$q, 10];
$q["storage"]
```

> ```
> {9, 10, 7, 8}
> ```

```
popQ[$q]
```

> ```
> 7
> ```

and so on. Now, when I try the obvious generalization to folding, I'm back where I started with the `... in the part assignment is not a symbol.`

```
Fold[pushQ, newQ[4], Range[1]]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[49]:= Set::setps: <|storage->{Null,Null,Null,Null},len->0,cap->4,iFront->1,iBack->1|> in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>
> During evaluation of In[49]:= Set::setps: <|storage->{Null,Null,Null,Null},len->0,cap->4,iFront->1,iBack->1|> in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>
> During evaluation of In[49]:= General::stop: Further output of Set::setps will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
> <|"storage" -> {Null, Null, Null, Null}, "len" -> 0, "cap" -> 4, "iFront" -> 1, "iBack" -> 1|>
> ```

Ok, I need some kind of symbol for `Set` to work.  A couple more attempts as follows produce the same results, and I did a bunch of tracing and printing, and couldn't see a good way through this:

```
Module[{$q = newQ[4]}, Fold[pushQ, $q, Range[1]]]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[48]:= Set::setps: <|storage->{Null,Null,Null,Null},len->0,cap->4,iFront->1,iBack->1|> in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>
> ```

```
Module[{$q = newQ[4]}, Fold[($q = pushQ[#1, #2]) &, $q, Range[1]]]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[44]:= Set::setps: <|storage->{Null,Null,Null,Null},len->0,cap->4,iFront->1,iBack->1|> in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>
> ```

**EDIT**:

This question is really about elegance because I *can* get meaningful, useful side effects with `Map` and `Scan`, as follows:

```
Module[{q = newQ[4]}, pushQ[q, #] & /@ Range[10]]
```

> ```
> {<|"storage" -> {1, Null, Null, Null}, "len" -> 1, "cap" -> 4, "iFront" -> 1, "iBack" -> 2|>, 
>    <|"storage" -> {1, 2, Null, Null}, "len" -> 2, "cap" -> 4, "iFront" -> 1, "iBack" -> 3|>, 
>    <|"storage" -> {1, 2, 3, Null}, "len" -> 3, "cap" -> 4, "iFront" -> 1, "iBack" -> 4|>, 
>    <|"storage" -> {1, 2, 3, 4}, "len" -> 4, "cap" -> 4, "iFront" -> 1, "iBack" -> 1|>,
>    <|"storage" -> {5, 2, 3, 4}, "len" -> 4, "cap" -> 4, "iFront" -> 2, "iBack" -> 2|>,
>    <|"storage" -> {5, 6, 3, 4}, "len" -> 4, "cap" -> 4, "iFront" -> 3, "iBack" -> 3|>, 
>    <|"storage" -> {5, 6, 7, 4}, "len" -> 4, "cap" -> 4, "iFront" -> 4, "iBack" -> 4|>,
>    <|"storage" -> {5, 6, 7, 8}, "len" -> 4, "cap" -> 4, "iFront" -> 1, "iBack" -> 1|>,
>    <|"storage" -> {9, 6, 7, 8}, "len" -> 4, "cap" -> 4, "iFront" -> 2, "iBack" -> 2|>,
>    <|"storage" -> {9, 10, 7, 8}, "len" -> 4, "cap" -> 4, "iFront" -> 3, "iBack" -> 3|>}
> ```