# Functional-Style Partial Application and the Accumulator Pattern?

Tags: function-construction, evaluation

Following up on [Functional-Style Fixed-Length Queue Object?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57539/functional-style-fixed-length-queue-object), I want to generalize it to a functional-style accumulator pattern. Lots of things *look like* accumulators, loosely defined as binary functions that take a state-carrying object as a first parameter, a datum as a second parameter, and return the state-carrying object. Such an accumulator can be scanned, mapped, or (theoretically, pending answer to the cited question) folded over sequences or streams of data to yield interesting results. Some things that look like accumulators are statistics, filters, smoothers, estimators, hidden Markov models (Kalman, Viterbi), controllers, I am sure many more.

For elegance, I'm interested in a functional style. To keep the example small, consider the following:

```
newAccumulator[] := <|"runningSum" -> 0|>;
SetAttributes[accumulate, HoldFirst];
accumulate[accumulator_, datum_?NumberQ] :=
  (accumulator[["runningSum"]] += datum;
   accumulator);
```

This will just keep a running sum, but we could easily keep higher-order statistics and such a thing can be quite rich and useful.

We can use this easily to compute [Gauss's Day-of-Reckoning Sum](http://www.americanscientist.org/issues/pub/gausss-day-of-reckoning), for example;

```
$myAccumulator = newAccumulator[];
Scan[accumulate[$myAccumulator, #] &, Range[100]];
$myAccumulator
```

> ```
> <|"runningSum" -> 5050|>
> ```

Now, it occurred to me, "wouldn't it be nice if we could write

```
Scan[partial[accumulate, $myAccumulator], Range[100]]
```

where

```
SetAttributes[partial, HoldRest];
partial[f_, arg_] := (f[arg_,#]&);
```

which I can unit-test as follows

```
partial[f, x][y]
```

> ```
> f[x, y]
> ```

and even generalize (just a little):

```
partial[f_, as__] := (f[Sequence @@ (Quiet @ Join[as, ##])] &);
```

and unit-test

```
partial[f, x, y][z, w]
partial[f, x][y]
partial[f, x][]
```

> ```
> f[x, y, z, w]
> f[x, y]
> f[x]
> ```

But, lo and behold, it doesn't work on my example:

```
$myAccumulator = newAccumulator[];
Scan[partial[accumulate, $myAccumulator], Range[100]]
$myAccumulator
```

> ```
> <|"runningSum" -> 0|>
> ```

This one has me clueless.

**EDIT**: The `HoldRest` attribute on `partial` does not seem to make a difference. I put it in there out of habit -- side-effecting functions often work best when they hold their arguments against premature evaluation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generalized definition of `partial` fails because the generated function looks like this:

```
partial[accumulate, $myAccumulator]

(* accumulate[Sequence@@Quiet[Join[$myAccumulator,##1]]]& *)
```

Note how `accumulate` will be called with only a single argument.  Since `accumulate` is `HoldFirst`, that argument will not be expanded into a sequence of arguments and therefore the sole two-argument definition of `partial` will never be applied.

`TracePrint` reveals the full story:

```
TracePrint[partial[accumulate, $myAccumulator][1]]
```

```
partial[accumulate,$myAccumulator][1]
 partial[accumulate,$myAccumulator]
  partial
  accumulate
 accumulate[Sequence@@Quiet[Join[$myAccumulator,##1]]]&
  Function
 1
(accumulate[Sequence@@Quiet[Join[$myAccumulator,##1]]]&)[1]
accumulate[Sequence@@Quiet[Join[$myAccumulator,1]]]
 accumulate
accumulate[Sequence@@Quiet[Join[$myAccumulator,1]]]
```

The final `accumulate` expression is inert and `$myAccumulator` is never updated.

The use of `Sequence` and `Join` to assemble the curried argument list is thus flawed.  The original definition of `partial` was very close -- it can be extended like this:

```
ClearAll@partial
SetAttributes[partial, HoldRest]
partial[f_, as__] := f[as, ##]&
```

This produces the correct results:

```
partial[accumulate, $myAccumulator]

(* accumulate[$myAccumulator, ##1] & *)

$myAccumulator = newAccumulator[];
Scan[partial[accumulate, $myAccumulator], Range[100]]
$myAccumulator

(* <|runningSum->5050|> *)
```

Beware that this simple redefinition of `partial` still contains an evaluation leak.  While the curried arguments are correctly preserved unevaluated (`$myAccumulator` in this example), the additional arguments are evaluated before applying `f` (the `datum` argument in this case).  For example:

```
partial[Hold, 1 + 1][2 + 2]

(* Hold[1 + 1, 4] *)
```

We can correct for this problem by a more elaborate definition:

```
ClearAll@partial
SetAttributes[partial, HoldAll]
partial[f_, as__] := Function[Null, f[as, ##], HoldAll]
```

Note how this last definition gives the returned function the `HoldAll` attribute so that none of the passed arguments are evaluated prematurely.  So, now:

```
partial[Hold, 1 + 1][2 + 2]

(* Hold[1 + 1, 2 + 2] *)
```

Comment: I think I see. The leak is not in the definition of partial itself, but in the definition of the function it returns.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin While my proposed revised definitions of `partial` were correct, my explanation as to why the original generalized definition failed was in error.  Please see my corrected and expanded explanation.